# How to force the emulator to simulate a tablet

Tags: android, eclipse, tablet, tablet-pc

I am not a noobie to android nor eclipse's android emulator, but, while reading a topic about how to use `Fragments` there was an illustration shows how `fragments` works on either `samrt phones` and `tablets`. Now, I would like to know if it is possible that the `emulator` can function as a `tablet`.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference between an phone and a tablet to Android.  One is just a bigger screen size.  So yes, the emulator functions like a tablet.

Comment: i would like to know, if there is any specific configuration to be set when creating a new `AVD` that I want to use it as a tablet?

Comment: Since there is no difference, no.  Just set the screen size you want.